# How exactly are arguments, that contain variables passed into functions?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have variable `a`and variable `b` in the `main` function:

```
int main() {
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
func(a, b);
}
```

Now, I have another function, whose parameters match the names of arguments:

```
int func(int a, int b) {
    return (a + b);
}
```

When I call the function, does that mean the parameters in `func` will be assigned with variables `a` and `b` from the main function? Why don't I get an `error: redeclaration of ‘int a’` error (and the same error with b)?

Comment: Learn about scope. The gist is they don't interfere with each other because they are in different scopes.

Comment: The *values* of the variables are passed to the function; it works exactly the same as `func(2,3)`. In the function, `a` and `b` are different variables that will have those values. (If you had to worry about what the caller of a function named their variables, programming would be impossible.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Well, if you're saying that the values of these variables are copied and assigned like int `a = 2, int b = 3`, then why referencing accesses actual variables from the `main` function?

Comment: Referencing them doesn't reference actual variables from `main`. Try replacing `func`'s body with `a = 9999;` and then see if the `a` in `main` changes. Spoiler: It won't. It's a different variable.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo So when I call `func`, value from `a` will be taken and what gets assigned in `func`'s parameters is basically `int a = 2`? Also when I talk about referencing, I mean `int &a`. That seems to access variables from `main` directly and when assigning value of 9999 to `a`, it does change.

Comment: @dfsdfd "*when assigning value of 9999 to a, it does change*" No, it [does not](https://godbolt.org/z/x4YPnP).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a fundamental tenet of C programming that is more suited to an introductory book or course.